# insert values with different delimiter

Tags: sql, ms-access

i want to insert values into a table, with an `INSERT INTO` statement but i would like to use a different delimiter (not a comma) how do i do this?

i dont want to use a comma for the following reason:

the data is in this format:

```
|something|somethingelse|something3 ,moretextinsamefield|

field1 = "something"
field2 = "somethingelse"
field3 = "something3 ,something4"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a comma?

Comment: You say you don't need to import a file, so where is the data you are trying to import into your table coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing SQL to do this will get very complicated very quickly, with a bunch of nested Mid() and InStr() functions.

Instead, I'd do it with a function that uses Split().

```
  Public Function SplitField(varInput As Variant, strDelimiter As String, lngItemRequested As Long) As Variant
    Dim varTemp As Variant
    Dim arrInput() As String

    varTemp = varInput
    If Left(varTemp, 1) = strDelimiter Then
       varTemp = Mid(varTemp, 2)
    End If
    If right(varTemp, 1) = strDelimiter Then
       varTemp = Left(varTemp, Len(varTemp) - 1)
    End If
    arrInput = Split(varTemp, strDelimiter)
    If lngItemRequested - 1 <= UBound(arrInput()) Then
       SplitField = arrInput(lngItemRequested - 1)
       If SplitField = vbNullString Then
          SplitField = Null
       End If
    Else
       SplitField = Null
    End If
  End Function
```

Then in SQL, you'd call it thus:

```
  INSERT INTO TargetTable( Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 )
  SELECT SourceTable.SourceField, SplitField([SourceField],"|",1),
    SplitField([SourceField],"|",2), 
    SplitField([SourceField],"|",3), 
    SplitField([SourceField],"|",4)
  FROM SourceTable
```

Note that the function I wrote can be used even when there is a variable number of subparts in the source field. That is, if some have 4 parts and some 2, it doesn't matter, as the function returns Null for the parts that aren't there.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use the Split function which lets you specify a delimiter:

```
Dim aValues As Variant
aValues = Split("|something|somethingelse|something3 ,something4", "|")
```

**ADDITION**

Here is some sample code in VBA.

```
Public Sub AppendValues()
    Const SOURCE_VALUES = "|something|somethingelse|something3 ,moretextinsamefield|"
    Dim aValues As Variant

    aValues = Split(SOURCE_VALUES, "|")

    Dim oDB As DAO.Database
    Dim oRS As DAO.Recordset

    Set oDB = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)
    Set oRS = oDB.OpenRecordset("Table1", dbOpenTable)

    oRS.AddNew
    oRS("Col1") = aValues(1)
    oRS("Col2") = aValues(2)
    oRS("Col3") = aValues(3)
    oRS.Update

    Set oRS = Nothing
    Set oDB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thomas this is a cool idea, so then how would i insert those values into a table please show me

Answer (score 2):

Would it be easier to do a pre-insert operation and clean up the data? Replace the `|`'s with `,`'s, and enclose all values in quotes (or something like that)?

If not, I think if you format the data in a text file, you can use Access to import text and specify that `|` is the delimiter, rather than `,`.

Comment: if i replace with a comma then that will not preserve the integrity because i have one field that has a comma within the string

Comment: @every_answer_gets_a_point: If you quote that field, or escape the comma (as `\,`) does that work for you? CSV files can have commas in the field values by simply putting quotes around the field: `"field1", "field 2, has, a, comma"`

Comment: Is there a reason that you have `|` as a delimeter, instead of a comma?

Comment: This (pre-insert operation to clean up data) seems like the best answer to your specific issue.  In your example if you enclose your value containing a value in single quotes (|'something3, something4'|) you should still be able to use commas as your seperator for the insert statement.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this article: [Pipe Delimited File into access database](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/5a342cb3-14f4-4498-8491-487f6bf067b5)

> Try this code.
>
> The approach is as given below.
>
> 1. Import the data from the text file to a temporary table ('Import')
> 2. Update existing records in the table ('Dest') by joining the imported
>      table and the existing table
> 3. Select the records from the 'Import' table which are not present
>      in the 'Dest' table
> 4. Insert these new records to the 'Dest'
>
> You need to modify the queries as per
>   your table structure.

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=G:\VBNET\Access\bin\dest.mdb")   
        'Import data to a temporary table   
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * INTO [import] FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;Database=G:\VBNET\Access\bin;Hdr=Yes].[Students.txt]", conn)   
        conn.Open()   
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()   
        'Update Existing records 
        Dim updateQuery As String = "UPDATE Dest INNER JOIN Import ON Dest.id = Import.F1 set Dest.Name = Import.F2"  
        Dim queryCmd As New OleDbCommand(updateQuery, conn)   
        queryCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()   

        Dim selectQuery = "select F1, F2, F3 from Import where F1 not in (select Id from Dest) "  
        queryCmd = New OleDbCommand(selectQuery, conn)   
        Dim dataReader As OleDbDataReader   
        dataReader = queryCmd.ExecuteReader()   

        Dim appendrecords As New ArrayList()   
        Dim insertQuery As String   

        While dataReader.Read()   

            Dim F1 As String = dataReader.GetString(0).ToString()   
            Dim F2 As String = dataReader.GetString(1).ToString()   
            Dim F3 As Integer = dataReader.GetInt32(2).ToString()   
            insertQuery = "insert into Dest values ('" & F1 & "', '" & F2 & "', " & F3 & ")"   
            appendrecords.Add(insertQuery)   

        End While   
        dataReader.Close()   

        Dim i As Integer   
        For i = 0 To appendrecords.Count - 1   
            Dim insertCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(appendrecords(i), conn)   
            insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()   
        Next 
        conn.Close()
```

Comment: thank you but this is too complex, i dont need to be importing a file

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to do this with an INSERT statement, it's simple.  Call the subroutine like this:

```
Call InsertValues("|something|somethingelse|something3 ,moretextinsamefield|")
```

Uncomment the Execute line to actually do the INSERT instead of just displaying the statement.

```
Public Sub InsertValues(ByVal pstrInput As String)
Dim i As Integer
Dim strSql As String
Dim strValList As String
Dim varValues As Variant

varValues = Split(pstrInput, "|")

'first and last array members are empty strings; skip them '
For i = 1 To 3
    strValList = strValList & ", " & Chr(34) & varValues(i) & Chr(34)
Next i
'strip off leading comma and space '
strValList = Mid(strValList, 3)
strSql = "INSERT INTO YourTable (field1, field2, field3)" & _
    vbNewLine & "Values (" & strValList & ");"
Debug.Print strSql
'CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError '
End Sub
```

Comment: I think my answer is more extensible and handles more variation in the source data.